# android - dynamic first radio button to be in true state

Tags: android, dynamic, radio-button, radio-group

in my android app i am tried to create a dynamic radio button, according to an arraylist size, inside a radio group using the following code

```
for (int aa = 0; aa < itemname.length(); aa++)
{
    String iname = itemname.getJSONObject(aa).getString("item");

    final RadioButton[] radioButton = new RadioButton[itemname.length()];
    radioButton[aa] = new RadioButton(this);
    radioGroup.addView(radioButton[aa]);
    radioButton[aa].setTextColor(R.color.black);
    radioButton[aa].setText(iname);
    radioButton[aa].setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.about_us_tab);                       

    radioButton[aa].setId(h_count);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new     android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
     {   
         public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
         {   
             int selectedBtn = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
          }
       });
       h_count++;
      }
  }
```

I am getting all the data in right order, and the onclick action of radio group is also working correctly.
But i want the the first radio button to be in selected mode. For this i tried using an if condition as follows

```
if(aa == 0)
    {
        radioButton[aa].setChecked(true);
        radioButton[aa].setId(h_count);
    }
```

But here the problem is, the first one is getting selected and in onclick action of radio group the first one is not getting deseleced, all others are working fine.

how to make the first one also deselected in onclick action of radio group

Answer (score 0):

try in this way and its working

```
for (int aa = 0; aa < itemname.length(); aa++)
{
    String iname = itemname.getJSONObject(aa).getString("item");

    final RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
    radioGroup.addView(radioButton;
    radioButton.setTextColor(R.color.black);
    radioButton.setText(iname);
    radioButton.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.about_us_tab);                       

    if(aa == 0)
    {
        radioButton.setChecked(true);
    }

    radioButton.setId(h_count);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new     android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {   
         public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
         {   
             int selectedBtn = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
         }
    });
    h_count++;
}
```